# Make column locked for editing by users in Sharepoint list

Tags: office-365, column, microsoft-flow, lock, planner

I currently have a SharePoint list that track open tickets for specific events.
I have a flow that runs on this when an item is added.

The flow creates an automatic due date (+5 days from when received), then creates a task for the creator in Planner, once the task is complete, it updates the list with the completion date, this way we can track what was resolved late.

However, the users put that the issue is resolved with a resolution date even though planner task is not complete, the flow will still update the resolution date from when complete.

However, we can't track the sheet correctly due to this. How can I lock the resolution date for editing by users, but still update via flow.

I am not able to use 3rd party applications and don't have SharePoint designer. Is there perhaps a way I can achieve this by using the JSON Format section for the column within SharePoint?